# how to check udev rules for 18.04 and android device

Tags: usb, android, 18.04, udev

I have a Samsung J2 Prime phone which fastboot cannot detect.
ADB detects when in MTP mode.
After booting phone to download mode lsusb shows my phone in download mode so I dont think its a driver issue.
I'm thinking maybe I don't have the correct udev rules.
Can someone please tell me how to manually check the rules, I haven't done much with Ubuntu config files before.

Thank you,

I added the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-android.rules with:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

and rebooted. Still the same problem.
My laptop only has USB2 ports so its not the usb3 bug.
Have been using sudo to run fastboot as root.
USB debugging is turned on the phone as is allow oem unlocking.

Comment: *not detected* issue is different from *no permission*. `udev` only helps with *no permission*. you need to be more specific about your problem

Comment: Could you add more info about device and its detection logs from: `lsusb`, `dmesg` , `udevadm monitor -u` , `udevadm info ...` . It hard to tell with little info as long we don't have similar device. Also have you tried another device and got fastboot working?